# Create section-level toc in a KOMA-script document that already uses minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook, minitoc

I have a long document which uses the KOMA-Script book class `scrbook` and I would like to add a section-level table of contents to a few rather long sections in my document. I am already using the `minitoc` package to provide part TOCs. The minitoc package also has a `secttoc` command, but this cannot be used along with the book class.

I have already tried using the `etoc` package, with the following code:

```
\section{My Section}
\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{3}
\localtableofcontents*
```

however, this seems to conflict with something in either `minitoc` or `scrbook` and didn't work.

Other resources seem to indicate that I might be able to use the built in `tocbasic` which is part of KOMA-Script, but I was not able to figure out how that would work from the documentation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%%% Language support %%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For MWE

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % makes subsubsections numbered

%%% TOC custimization %%%
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1} % only includes parts and chapters (not sections) in main TOC
\mtcsetdepth{parttoc}{1} % only includes chapters and sections (not subsections) in part TOCs

\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle} % prettier TOC
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} %use 'KOMAlike" if you don't want dots

\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Contents} %renames the part TOC to match main TOC

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


\begin{document}
\doparttoc

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\ \\
\vspace{5cm}
{\Huge Title}
\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
%insert Sect TOC HERE
\lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.1}
  \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.1.1}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.1.2}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.1.3}
    \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.2}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.3}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.4}
  \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.4.1}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.4.2}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.4.3}
    \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.5}
  \lipsum
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you like a solution with `etoc` and without `minitoc`?

Answer (score 4):

If you need such a section table of contents only for a few section (or if you use `lualatex` that does not have TeX's file handle restrictions) you could indeed use `tocbasic`. Add this to the end of your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifusesectiontoc% Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
\newcommand*{\sectiontoc}{% new command to generate and show a section toc
  \usesectiontoctrue% switch on section-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@subtoc{toc\thesection}% extension of the section-toc-file, e.g., toc1.1
  \expandafter\DeclareNewTOC\expandafter{\ext@subtoc}% declare a new toc file
  \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
    \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth% we want entries down to subsection
    \expandafter\listoftoc\expandafter*\expandafter{\ext@subtoc}% show the toc without any heading
  \end{minipage}\par
  \bigskip\noindent% add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent the following text
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifusesectiontoc% if section toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@subtoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\section{\usesectiontocfalse}{}{}% automatically switch of section toc entries at start of every \section
\makeatother
```

Then use `\sectiontoc` right after the `\section` that should have a section toc. This will produce, e.g.,

[image]

Note: You cannot use `\sectiontoc` for not numbered section, e.g., made by `\addsec` or `\section*`. If you need such section ToCs, you cannot use `\thesection` for the file extension.

Comment: Why is this solution only useful if "only for a few section[s]"?

Comment: @ScottWilton: Because it needs an output file handle for each section ToC and these are hard limited if you are using pdflatex. If you are using lualatex the file handles are limited by the OS only. So with lualatex you can use it for a lot of section. For pdflatex you can try the alpha package [`scrwfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrwfile) to avoid the file handle problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at this briefly for usage of `etoc`. The main obstacle is that one of KOMA, tocbasic, or minitoc defines an `xpart` sectioning level which is unknown to `etoc`. The simplest for your usage is to let `etoc` ignore it (it seems to always follow a `part` line in the toc file hence `etoc` will still know where local TOC should end even if ignoring `xpart`) and also to prevent `etoc` from redefining `\tableofcontents`:

```
\let\withoutetoctableofcontents\tableofcontents
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetlevel{xpart}{6}% makes xpart invisible to etoc
\let\tableofcontents\withoutetoctableofcontents

\begin{document}
```

Then you can do your `etoc` local toc this way for example:

```
\section{Section 1.1}

\etocsetnexttocdepth{3}
\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\localtableofcontents


\lipsum
```

Your example thus modified (nota bene there is a comment

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1} % only includes parts and chapters (not sections) in main TOC
```

which looks wrong to me, it should be `0` not `-1` or at least it would be in `book` class, perhaps KOMA is different)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%%% Language support %%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For MWE

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % makes subsubsections numbered

%%% TOC custimization %%%
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1} % only includes parts and chapters (not sections) in main TOC
\mtcsetdepth{parttoc}{1} % only includes chapters and sections (not subsections) in part TOCs

\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle} % prettier TOC
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} %use 'KOMAlike" if you don't want dots

\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Contents} %renames the part TOC to match main TOC

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\let\withoutetoctableofcontents\tableofcontents
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetlevel{xpart}{6}
\let\tableofcontents\withoutetoctableofcontents

\begin{document}
\doparttoc

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\ \\
\vspace{5cm}
{\Huge Title}
\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}

\etocsetnexttocdepth{3}
\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\localtableofcontents


\lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.1}
  \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.1.1}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.1.2}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.1.3}
    \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.2}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.3}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.4}
  \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.4.1}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.4.2}
    \lipsum
    \subsubsection{Sub Sub Sec 1.1.4.3}
    \lipsum
  \subsection{Sub Sec 1.1.5}
  \lipsum
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's `minitoc` that defines `xpart`, `xchapter`, and `xsect` levels. BTW: KOMA-Script defines `\parttocdepth`, `\chaptertocdepth` etc. so you do not need to know the numbers.

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks for info, similar `\etocsetlevel{xchapter}{6}` etc would then be needed if they ever appear in the main `.toc` file (which is the only file etoc uses)