# repeat tableofcontents, tableofcontents only for current section

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\tableofcontents
\section{1}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
\section{2}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{A}
\subsection{B}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Only the first tableofcontents is printed. The second and third shall only print the tableofcontents for the current section. How do I achieve that?

Comment: This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430622/134144 should also be applicable to your case.

Comment: perfect. thank you