# Create section-level toc in a KOMA-script document with tcolorbox and tocbasic library

Tags: tcolorbox, minipage, minitoc

I just trying to create TOC for every chapter. Therefore I created a command `\setchaptertoc` according to the question [517733](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517733/using-koma-script-for-defining-toc-for-each-chapter). The problem appears when chapter contains too much section. In that case the TOC overfull the page, and it is not continued in next page. I try to use [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package instead of minipage. The compilation result is shown in figure below.

I also look on question "[How to make minipage spanning multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271410/how-to-make-minipage-spanning-multiple-pages)", where breakable tcolorbox environment is used.

I am using Lualatex and package scrwfile, so I am not restricted with @writefile for toc.

[image]

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{scrwfile}% avoid trouble with the limited number of write handles
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502077
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516093
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430594/use-minitoc-with-koma-script-scrbook/502856
 \makeatletter

 \newif\ifusechaptertoc                % Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries
                                    % to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
 \newcommand*{\chaptertoc}[2][\thechapter]{  % new command to generate and show a chapter toc
 \usechaptertoctrue                  % switch on chapter-toc-entries
 \edef\ext@chaptoc{tcc#1}            % extension of the chapter-toc-file, e.g., tcc1
 \DeclareNewTOC{\ext@chaptoc}        % declare a new toc file
 %\addsec*{Contents}                 % header of the chaptertoc
 \setchapterpreamble{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
     % \hrulefill\par
       \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth  % we want entries down to subsection
       \listoftoc*{\ext@chaptoc}       % show the toc without header
    \end{tcolorbox}%
     \par\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par % \par\bigskip\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par
     \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces % add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent 
    }                                    % the following text
 }
  \xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{        % patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
   \ifusechaptertoc                    % if chapter toc entries should be generated
     \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{}
        {\expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@chaptoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}}% do it
   \fi
  }{}{}
  \xpretocmd\chapter{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{} % automatically switch of chapter toc entries at start 
                                          % of every \chapter
\makeatother

\newcommand\setchaptertoc[1][]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc}}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc[#1]}}%
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{My Part I}

\setchaptertoc
    \chapter{My chapter I}
        \section{My first section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 1th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 2nd subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 3rd subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 4th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 5th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 6th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 7th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 8th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 9th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 10th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
    \section{My second section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext    
    \section{My third section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext       
    \section{My fourth section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext    
    \section{My fifth section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext  
    \section{My sixth section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext    
    \section{My seventh section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext           
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the toc needed to be inside a `tcolorbox`?

Comment: Not necessarily. I like to use tcolorbox, for its great customization options

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use the `minitoc` package to get a toc per chapter.
The `strip` environment defined in the `cuted` package is used here to make the minitoc take all the page width in a two columns document.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    
    \usepackage{minitoc,cuted}
    \dominitoc

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{My Part I}

%\setchaptertoc
    \chapter{My chapter I}
    
    \begin{strip}
    \minitoc
    \end{strip}
        \section{My first section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 1th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 2nd subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 3rd subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 4th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 5th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 6th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 7th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 8th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 9th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My 10th subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
    \section{My second section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext    
    \section{My third section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext       
    \section{My fourth section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext    
    \section{My fifth section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext  
    \section{My sixth section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext    
    \section{My seventh section}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My second subsection}
            \blindtext     
        \subsection{My third subsection}
            \blindtext
        \subsection{My fourth subsection}
            \blindtext           
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested your code. I received the error: chapter 1.
(grain0073a.mtc1)
! Undefined control sequence.
\@outputdblcol ...i \@combinedblfloats \@setmarks 
                                                  \@outputpage \begingroup \...
l.26     \end{strip}
First compilation was fine, but the second not. Also usage minitoc together with komascript is deprecated.

Comment: @JardaFait . This seams weird to me because I have tested the code on overleaf with luatex engine and I get no errors!