# Appendix prefix not showing in TOC when using partial ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendix

I tried to use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517754/259954) to make partial ToC in my document, but when I added my appendix, it changed the behavior of the appendix package. In spite of putting `\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}`, "Appendices" and "Appendix A" do not show at the ToC.

The suggested solution is not providing the desired output, as I would like the Appendices to show in the partial ToC and not in the general ToC.

I think the problem is related with `\tocbasic@addxcontentsline` or `\listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}`. The .aux file does differentiate between .toc and .tcpI, but it discriminates the `\contentsline {chapter}{Appendices}{9}{}\protected@file@percent` and `\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix \numberline {A}Chapter appendix}{11}{}\protected@file@percent`, leaving the first one without entry in the .tcpI and it does not display what is before `\numberline` in the second.

Is there any way to change this behavior? TIA.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Partial TOC
\makeatletter
\newif\ifuseparttoc
\newcommand*{\parttoc}[1][\thepart]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
\useparttoctrue% switch on part-toc-entries
\edef\ext@parttoc{tcp#1}% extension of the part-toc-file, e.g., tcpI
\DeclareNewTOC[
    listname=My Content,
    %unset=onecolumn% if the part toc should use twocolumn
]{\ext@parttoc}% declare a new toc file
\begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth% we want entries down to chapter
    \listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}% show the toc with header
\endgroup
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
\ifuseparttoc% if part toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@parttoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
\fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\part{\useparttocfalse}{}{}% automatically switch of part toc entries at start of every \part
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{PART 1}
    \parttoc
    \chapter{Something}
    \blindtext
    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Chapter appendix}
        \blindtext
    \end{appendices}
    \chapter{Non appendix chapter}
\end{document}
```

After some research, I've found [this other solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501439/259954) which approaches the same problem from a different perspective. Despite trying to understand the code, I have failed to make the appropriate changes to make it work as a partial ToC for each `\part`. This is another **MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Works with or without hyperref.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  % Macros for resetting and appending to the variables that store the part tocs.
  \def\@parttoc@toc@reset{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @parttoc@toc@\@parttoc@part@num\endcsname{}%
  }
  \def\@parttoc@toc@append{%
    \expandafter\gappto\csname @parttoc@toc@\@parttoc@part@num\endcsname
  }
  % The parsing macro, that goes through the toc file and creates the part toc macros.
  \def\@parttoc@parse@tocfile{%
    % We only need to do this once.
    \let\@part@parse@tocfile\relax
    \begingroup
      \def\@parttoc@part@num{0}%
      \@parttoc@toc@reset
      \makeatletter
      \IfFileExists{\jobname.toc}{%
        \CatchFileDef\@tmpa{\jobname.toc}{}%
        \expandafter\@parttoc@parse@head
        \@tmpa
        \contentsline\@parttoc@parse@stop%
      }{}%
    \endgroup
  }
  \def\@parttoc@part@string{part}
  \def\@parttoc@parse@stop{\@parttoc@parse@stop}%
  \long\def\@parttoc@parse@head#1\contentsline#2{%
    \@parttoc@toc@append{#1}%
    \ifx\@parttoc@parse@stop#2%
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \begingroup
      \def\@tmpa{#2}%
      \ifx\@tmpa\@parttoc@part@string
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\@parttoc@parse@cline@part
      \else
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\@parttoc@parse@cline@other
      \fi
    \fi
    {#2}%
  }
  \def\@parttoc@parse@cline@other{%
    \@parttoc@toc@append{\contentsline}%
    \@parttoc@parse@head
  }
  \def\@parttoc@parse@cline@part#1#2#3{%
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1##2\@nil{%
        \endgroup
        \def\@parttoc@part@num{##1}%
      }%
    #2\@nil
    \@parttoc@toc@reset
    \expandafter\@parttoc@parse@head\@parttoc@parse@gobble@hyperrefargs
  }
  % A macro for printing the current part toc.
  \def\@parttoc@toc@print{%
    \begingroup
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{\partocdepth}%
      \parindent 0pt%
      \chapter*{\contentsname}%
      \csname @parttoc@toc@\arabic{part}\endcsname
      \@parttoc@toc@afterhook
    \endgroup
  }
  \newcommand*\partocdepth{3}
  \def\@parttoc@toc@afterhook{}
  \newcommand\parttocafter[1]{%
    \def\@parttoc@toc@afterhook{#1}%
  }
  % Set everything up.
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    % When hyperref is loaded, \contentsline has one more argument.
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{\let\protect\@parttoc@parse@gobble@hyperrefargs\protect\@gobble}%
    }{%
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{\let\protect\@parttoc@parse@gobble@hyperrefargs\protect\@empty}%
    }%
    % When the aux file is read in the first time, the toc file will be parsed.
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \protect\@parttoc@parse@tocfile
    }%
    % Automatically print the part toc after each part title.
    \apptocmd\scr@@startpart{\@parttoc@toc@print}{}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{PART 1}
\chapter{Something}
\blindtext
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Chapter appendix}
  \blindtext
\end{appendices}
\chapter{Non appendix chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`

Comment: This adds the appendix in the main ToC but I would like it in the partial ToC. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `\addappheadtotoc` (provided by package `appendix`) to get the entry »Appendices« in the partial TOC:

```latex
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{% original definition see package appendix
  \phantomsection
  \addchaptertocentry{}{\appendixtocname}%
}
```

For the prefix »Appendix« in TOC redefine KOMA-Script command `\addchaptertocentry` inside the `appendices` environment:

```
\xapptocmd{\appendices}{\useappendixprefixintoc}{}{}
\newcommand{\useappendixprefixintoc}{
  \let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
  \renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
    \IfArgIsEmpty{##1}
      {\originaladdchaptertocentry{##1}{##2}}
      {\originaladdchaptertocentry{}{\appendixname~##1\protect\autodot\ ##2}}
  }%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Partial TOC
\makeatletter
\newif\ifuseparttoc
\newcommand*{\parttoc}[1][\thepart]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
\useparttoctrue% switch on part-toc-entries
\edef\ext@parttoc{tcp#1}% extension of the part-toc-file, e.g., tcpI
\DeclareNewTOC[
    listname=My Content,
    %unset=onecolumn% if the part toc should use twocolumn
]{\ext@parttoc}% declare a new toc file
\begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth% we want entries down to chapter
    \listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}% show the toc with header
\endgroup
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
\ifuseparttoc% if part toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@parttoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
\fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\part{\useparttocfalse}{}{}% automatically switch of part toc entries at start of every \part
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC


\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{% original definition see package appendix
  \phantomsection
  \addchaptertocentry{}{\appendixtocname}%
}
\xapptocmd{\appendices}{\useappendixprefixintoc}{}{}
\newcommand{\useappendixprefixintoc}{
  \let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
  \renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
    \IfArgIsEmpty{##1}
      {\originaladdchaptertocentry{##1}{##2}}
      {\originaladdchaptertocentry{}{\appendixname~##1\protect\autodot\ ##2}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{PART 1}
\parttoc
\chapter{Something}
\blindtext
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Chapter appendix}
  \blindtext
\end{appendices}
\chapter{Non appendix chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]